# Why does Passenger restarts my node js app every day?

Tags: node.js, nginx, passenger

I have an nodejs app. Passenger restarts the app every 3:30. And there is nothing in "err.log". There is no "restart.txt" file anywhere but it restarts. How can i do prevent this? Why does this happen?